# How to plot points on same chart in a loop and not separate charts?

Tags: python, loops, graph, charts

I am trying to plot multiple points in a text file onto the same chart within a loop.  However, currently my code plots each point as a separate chart.

modname        = ['model_a', 'model_b', 'model_c', 'model_d', 'model_e', 'model_f']

d = pd.read_table("sample.txt")

```
for mdl in modname:
  pod=d[ (d.MODEL == mdl) & (d.SCORE == "PODY")].VALUE
  far=d[ (d.MODEL == mdl) & (d.SCORE == "FAR")].VALUE
  csi=d[ (d.MODEL == mdl) & (d.SCORE == "CSI")].VALUE
  bias=d[ (d.MODEL == mdl) & (d.SCORE == "FBIAS")].VALUE
  sro = 1 - far

  print mdl
  print pod
  print far
  print csi
  print bias
  print sro

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

for mdl in modname:
  plt.scatter(sro,pod,color=leg_col[i],marker='.',s=750)
  plt.savefig(imgdir+outf)
```

I shortened aspects in the second loop for the example here.  I expect one chart with 6 points on it but I get 6 charts with one point on them.  I'm not sure if I have my loop set up incorrectly or I'm saving my data wrong.  The data is coming from a text file with headers separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
for mdl in modname:
  plt.scatter(sro,pod,color=leg_col[i],marker='.',s=750)
  plt.savefig(imgdir+outf)
```

to

```
for mdl in modname:
  plt.scatter(sro,pod,color=leg_col[i],marker='.',s=750)

plt.savefig(imgdir+outf)
```

you are saving every loop

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this and it now only plots and saves a chart with the last point in the loop rather than all points on the same chart.

Comment: you are looping over modname with mdl as the iterator but not actually using mdl in the loop..you are plotting the same point over and over..either that or something weird is going on, this code works for me with test scatter data